# Trouble running waitress as a service on Windows Server 2003

Tags: python, windows-services, waitress

So I've written a windows service in python which starts a subprocess that runs a Waitress server, monitors a directory for changes, and restarts the server when a change is detected. On Windows 7, everything works fine. On Windows Server 2003, where I have to deploy this server, the server fails to bind to its port. I've tried running the service as several different users, including NetworkService, but nothing seems to work. There's nothing in the waitress logs, either. How can I even debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, March, a bit late.  You can't debug without more info.  I'd turn the logging all the way to debug, if not already done.  I'd also check the NT event log.

The only things coming to mind are the firewall, and extra restrictions on apps in server.  If possible, try adding an exception for your app.